# How to fill flip flop clock truth table?

Tags: clock, flipflop, truth-table

I have this truth table that I want to fill, however, I have no idea how to read the flip-flops on the left. Can anyone provide me a minimal example of how to approach this problem?

[image]

EDIT: drawing this table as something like this ... will be helpful for newbies.

[image]

Comment: Just fill J1 K1 J2 K2 and then at the next clock, apply the table of JK flip flop. In your first line J1=Q2\=1, K1=1, J2=Q1=0, K2=Q1\=1 ... So if J1=1 and K1=1 ... J2=0 and K2=1 ... what happens for FF1 and FF2 ?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Is this a homework/coursework question?

Comment: Have you-read any JK datasheet?

Comment: @Antonio51 one more question, I dont understand the Q1 and Q2, at first it is 0 0, for the next row it will be 01, then 10 and 11? Or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: @Antonio51, can you tell me if this looks ok? https://i.imgur.com/gBF2wyk.png

Comment: Seems to be an error on 3rd line (clk pulse = 2). Remember that it is a counter by 3 (see simulation).

Comment: For helping more, see this picture where I have added some info ... that helps fulfilling table ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMo5j.png When completed, add it to your question.

Comment: @Antonio51 thanks, fully understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone provide me a minimal example of how to approach this problem?
> NB: as @Tony Stewart EE75 pointed, you need "understand" the JK datasheet and "functions" tables of JK device block.

See [this](https://www.gatevidyalay.com/jk-flip-flops/) for informations about "truth" and "excitation" tables (a little "error", JK changes to RS ?).

For reference, EE&O, did not verify tables.

[image]

NB: **Qn** at the very left of the next picture ( **K**arnaugh **map**) should be **Qn+1**!

[image]

[image]

Making a simulation will help a little, and **help fill the table**.
This is a "shortcut", for the "**first time**".
Remember that **only** the **falling edge** of the clock is meaningful.
All simulations must begins with a "clear"...
Two simulations are made. **See only the first part (Q1,Q2)** for starting.

The first with "ideal" FF (**Q1,Q2 : no delay**=DO_EFF),
the second with "real" FF (**Q3,Q4 : SN7476**).

This will make the difference between the "**ideal**" world and the "**real**" world.

[image]

Comment: Please don't hand out complete solutions to homework problems.

Comment: Ok. My first comment is the real approach to this question. So, the OP table is not completed. And the use of the truth table is, de facto, the "exercise" and is not yet fulfilled.